# VBA to copy and process paragraphs and tables from one Word document to another

Tags: vba, ms-word

My scenario is that I want to copy and clean up SOME of the content from Word doc1 and store the sanitized content (with newly assigned styles) in doc2. I know how to loop over the paragraphs, recognize the ones that I want, and copy them into doc2 and how to assign new styles there.

I can also loop over the doc1.Tables collection and copy tables.

But I cannot figure out how to place the doc1 tables in the appropriate place in doc2. I would love to use a loop like this that kept the relative positions of paragraphs and tables consistent:

```
Foreach (object o in doc1) 
   if (o.type = paragraph) then
      if (I like the paragraph) then
         copy the paragraph to doc2
      endif
   else if (o.type = table) then
      if (I like the table for copying) then
         copy the table to doc2
      end if
   endif
next
```

But I don't know if that loop style (looping over objects) is possible or reasonable in VBA. I can't find any examples of it. Any other approach needs some way to associate a table with some position, bookmark, range, or text in the sequence of paragraphs in the document. But since I am currently only copying part of the doc1 text, I could easily not copy over whatever the tables are anchored to.

I'm almost to the point of copying over the "wholestory" of doc1 to doc2 and then deleting parts that I don't need and restyling parts that I do need, all in situ.

Is it possible to use the kind of loop shown above to sequentially copy things (paragraphs, tables, images, etc.) from doc1 to doc2? If so, what does the object testing code look like? (`if o.type is type.paragraph`)? Should I even be trying that approach, or is it a waste of time? Thank you

Comment: Deleting the parts you don't want sounds much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looping paragraphs, check whether the paragraph is in a table. That will let you do things in order, as far as tables are concerned

```
Foreach (object o in doc1) 
   if (o.type = paragraph) then
      if (paragraph.Range.Information(wdWithinTable) Then
         do something with the entire table
      elseif (I like the paragraph) then
         copy the paragraph to doc2
      endif
next
```

Note, however, that there's really no reliable way to handle *all possible* Word objects using the object model. Most especially, graphical objects formatted with text wrap (as opposed to in-line) are very complex.

The more reliable way to work through document content in the order of "things" is to leverage the Word Open XML file format, where the actual underlying content is available.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed to know. I never thought of using objects and inspecting the type.